# DNX beta8+, ASP.NET 5 and Kestrel in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, asp.net-core, dnx

As of [ASP.NET Announcement 69](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69):

> "ASP.NET 5 applications run in IIS have been hosted by a component named Helios" and In beta8, we're discontinuing the "Helios" IIS host..

Also:

> Hosting ASP.NET 5 applications in IIS will now be achieved using the IIS HttpPlatformHandler configured to forward through to the ASP.NET 5 Kestrel server. This native IIS module, manages the launching of an external application host process (in this case dnx.exe) and the routing of requests from IIS to the hosted process.

The problem I have right now is that I've spent a few days stumbling through the internet looking how to host DNX application with `HttpPlatformHandler` in Azure and achieved nothing working.

What steps I should take to migrate from ASP.NET 5 beta7 to ASP.NET 5 beta 8?

Comment: Why did anyone downvote it? Please comment if you did.
Also, when trying to run sample project @davidfowl pointed in the announcement (KestrelServerOnAzure) I get this in Azure:
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

Comment: I'm not the one who down voted but if I were guessing I would say because beta8 is not finished and not released yet, they have merely announced what they are working on and what will change.

Comment: If you are using beta8 now you are on dev bits. Wait for official beta8.

Comment: `HttpPlatformHandler` is probably not supported in Azure yet because they haven't officialy released beta 8 yet.
The ASP.NET team is pretty much bang-on to their deadlines. If this is still the case for the next iteration, we should have the [official beta 8 on Oct 5](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap).

Comment: As far as I understand, HttpPlatformHandler already exists in higher IIS versions (e.g. not Win7). IIS8+ is required. Since the behavior is documented for node/tomcat/etc. it is a matter of Kestrel .... can you tell us somre more details where you fail?

Comment: I get `The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.` when I try using `HttpPlatformHandler`, which says nothing about the actual error. Just that it got an error.

Comment: Please take a look at answer in the Github repository https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364#issuecomment-148567294

Comment: It can be connected to the version of HttpPlatformHandler. Everywhere you get a link, it's 1.0, but really it will work properly on 1.2 as far as I understand, you can check this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255222/running-mvc-6-beta-8-application-on-iis/33258102#33258102

Comment: A working templates update and more info can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx