# What are these Error Msg from Asp.net core 2.0 WebApi and Krestrel

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I created an aspnet Core 2.0 WebApi Code First (work with SQL Server 2017 Database). I have successfully deployed it to Local IIS in my PC.

This is the error msg when I did a GET  with Postman :

```
Error: 0 - Unexpected exception in FrameConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
Error: 0 - UbReadCb
Error: 0 - Unexpected exception in FrameConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
Error: 0 - Unexpected exception in FrameConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
Error: 0 - UbReadCb
```

I dont know what they mean. Can you help.

Thanks

Comment: This might be a Postman issue. Did you try `GET` with cURL or some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same errors in log, postman shows "The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port" error when I call API methods.

Googled it and found this thread:

[ASP.NET Core 1.0 on IIS error 502.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I'm going to update ASPNetCore and NetCore runtimes and iisreset after.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Finally found this one and it saved me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756042/net-core-publish-to-iis-http-error-502-3-bad-gateway-the-specified-cgi-ap?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

I've enabled logging in web.config, then created 'logs' directory inside published project, then I noticed which problem in my code I have and fixed it.