# AspNetCoreModule - HTTP Error 502.3

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .Net Core 1.1.0 web app. I've been happily building and debugging using IISExpress and Visual Studio. Now I want to publish the app and host it on my own web server behind normal IIS.

Steps:

1. Ran `dotnet publish`, which packaged everything up into a publish
   folder
2. Created a new App Pool in IIS with .NET CLR Version set to
   "No Managed Code"
3. Created a new Application under Default Web Site,
   using the new app pool, with the Physical Path set to the publish
   folder created in step 1.

When trying to access the URL for the site, I get `HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway`, saying the module the error is coming from is AspNetCoreModule.

This is with Managed Pipeline Mode for the app pool set to Integrated. If I set it to Classic, I get 502.5 - Process Failure. Windows event logs don't have anything useful.

This is the web.config for the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: This is the WebHostBuilder definition:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .ConfigureServices(s => s.AddRouting())
            .Configure(app =>
            {
                SetupRoutes(app);
                app.UseDefaultFiles();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
            })
            .Build();
        host.Run();
```

Comment: Are you using Kestrel? Show your `WebHostBuilder` definition

Comment: I *think* I found the problem. I had nuget packages added using VS 2017 (so in .csproj, but not in project.json) - publishing from the command line failed because it couldn't find them. I can see the site in IIS now. Still a bit confused, because CLI publish worked before...

Comment: Run `dotnet myapp.dll` from folder where you published your app. Is everything starts/works OK? If yes - problem only "with real IIS". Edit `web.config`, change `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true`, restart app, refresh page in browser and look into logfile under `logs\stdout`.

Comment: @Dmitry I can run `dotnet myapp.dll` in console and it starts and serves. Looks like my IIS is the problem. I've enabled `stdout` logs but the files it creates are all blank. I get 502.3 Bad Gateway - Connection error while trying to route the request, error code: 0x800700002. I've searched everywhere and still am, but can't figure out what the problem is. Bad module? I have reinstalled it. I'm stumped.

Comment: My issue was the HttpPlatformHandler 1.0, needed to install 1.2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255222/running-mvc-6-beta-8-application-on-iis

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the proper runtime environment installed?

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current/runtime

Your web.config is pointing to a module AspNetCoreModule, can you see it properly installed in the "Modules" list of your application under IIS?

Comment: I can see my module in the module list and it is enabled. Does that mean it's properly installed? I do have all environments installed.